# Redirecting Bounced Emails not working with mail.smtp.host using JavaMail API

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

Redirecting bounced email is not working for me even after I tried with various ports (587, 465, and 25 ), SMTP Servers (smtp.gmail.com, smtp.live.com, and smtp.mail.yahoo.com ), Message objects (MimeMessage, Message, and SMTPMessage), and JavaMail API methods (message.addFrom, message,setReplyTo, and message.setHeader). I also tried to change javax.mail jar versions 1.4, 1.5 and etc. Everywhere in the stackoverflow they are saying, setting the other email to mail.smtp.from should work. But all my bounced emails are going back to sender. Not to the specified email address. Can someone help me to redirect it to a new email address? 
Here is the code I am using

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;

import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPMessage;

public class SendEmail {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Properties properties=new Properties();
     InputStream input=new FileInputStream("SendEmail.properties");
     properties.load(input);
       // String smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
      String smtpServer = "smtp.live.com";
      int port = 587;
      final String userid = "myemail@hotmail.com";//change accordingly
      final String password = properties.getProperty("EMAIL_PASSWORD1");
      String contentType = "text/html";
      String subject = "test: bounce an email to a different address " +
                "from the sender";
      String to = "bounceee@fauxmail.com";//some invalid address
      String bounceAddr = "bounceremail@gmail.com";//change accordingly
      String body = "Test: get message to bounce to a separate email address";

      Properties props = new Properties();

      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpServer);
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
      props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
      props.put("mail.smtp.from", bounceAddr);

      Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props,
         new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
               return new PasswordAuthentication(userid, password);
            }
         });

     // MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
      SMTPMessage message=new SMTPMessage(mailSession);
      message.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse(userid));
      message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
      message.setHeader("Return-path", bounceAddr);
      message.setSubject(subject);
      message.setContent(body, contentType);


      Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();
      try {
         System.out.println("Sending ....");
         transport.connect(smtpServer, port, userid, password);
         transport.sendMessage(message,
            message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
         System.out.println("Sending done ...");
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.err.println("Error Sending: ");
         e.printStackTrace();

      }
      transport.close();
   }// end function main()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public servers are unlikely to allow you to set the envelope from address to an address that they don't know you own, so as to prevent you from indirectly sending spam in the form of a bounced message.  If the server won't let you use it as a regular From address, you probably can't use it as an envelope from address either.  For Gmail, [this page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en) will tell you how to use a different address.

Note that you can see what envelope from address is being used by turning on [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and looking for the MAIL FROM line.